# Multiple UIViewControllers in "one" view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, view

I am making an app where I have multiple different screens that does different things. I have it all working with pop/push in an UINavigationController.

The layout is then something like this. The gray is each "uiviewcontroller", the rectangle is part of the background-picture and the RGB is the 'content' in each uiviewcontroller.

[image: img1]

I want to make it seem that all of the different screens are in the same "space". Like the next image.

I have been playing with custom segues and it "kind of" works. It removes the "push"/"pop" visual and it animates smoothly, it works great if the background is of one color. But that's not the case, in fact my background will have an animation where it spins ever so slowly.

[image: img2]

So how should I go about this?

Things I've tried or thought about

1. Custom segues. Require a lot of fiddly animations, not sure if I should pursue this as it seems like a hack (eg I am now animating the background separately to make it look like it is stationary while the RGB (content) moves.)
2. Transitions, I've just looked at this but if I am not mistaken it will have the same issues as above.
3. Some way of adding 3 UIViewControllers into a UIScrollView (or similar) and somehow "change" the active UIViewController/delegate/something depending on which screen I am currently watching.
4. Each RGB would be it's own UIView and managed by one big UIViewController.

I've been sitting on this problem for a good 2 days now but I am not sure how to best go about it.

**EDIT:** I used the UIPageViewController solution below and this is the resulting "app".

[image: result]

Comment: As of iOS 8 there's UISplitViewController. Have you looked into that?

Comment: No, but I need it to work on iOS7 (and maybe 6) so that's unfortunately not applicable to the current situation. Thanks though.

Comment: Yup, that's why I asked in a comment ;). Good luck (by the way... Containers are probably the way to go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using UIPageViewController? If you want change the UIViewController with swipe gesture, it will be the answer. It' available from iOS 6.

RootVC.h

```
@interface RootVC : UIPageViewController
@end
```

RootVC.m

```
@interface RootVC () <UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
{
    NSArray *_viewControllers;
}
@end

@implementation RootVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    LeftViewController *lv = [[LeftViewController alloc] init];
    CenterViewController *cv = [[CenterViewController alloc] init];
    RightViewController *rv = [[RightViewController alloc] init];
    _viewControllers = @[lv, cv, rv];

    [self setViewControllers:@[cv] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
[self setDelegate:self];
[self setDataSource:self];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSInteger index = [_viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    if(index > 0)
    {
        index--;
        return [_viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSInteger index = [_viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    if(index < 2)
    {
        index++;
        return [_viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I will have a look at it.

Comment: I added a sample code. It's easy and you can use all UIViewController delegates with it.

Comment: Thanks, one question though. Do you know if the added UIViewControllers can have a transparent background? So that all of them will appear to have the same one even when scrolling left/right between them?

Comment: set view controller's view transparent and set RootVC's view as UIImageView or something.

Comment: Alright I'll make this the answer as I will be using this for now. It produced the intended results exactly as I imagined. Thanks. Here is the result http://i.imgur.com/qbtQwIq.gif.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your view controllers in container views? Maybe it will fit your needs.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102

Answer (score 0):

You don't need three UIViewControllers.

1. add three UIView sub objects to your UIViewController's UIView,
   adjusting the frame.origin.x for each (so they are either on screen
   or not).
2. Add a swipe gesture recogniser to your UIViewController for
   right+left,
3. then when it's triggered, move the views on or off screen as needed. You can use the standard UIView AnimateWithDuration method, or a more custom CAAnimation.

Comment: You could instead use a UIPanGestureRecogniser, if you want to 'pan' the views on or off screen.

Comment: As my "number 4" states, yes I've thought about that. But how would I deal with the methods/delegates for each those views? Each one is kind of advanced. Let's assume each one of them contains a UITableView and does very different things with their respective delegates. How would I divide the code in a nice manner?

Comment: Your question didn't mention UITableView objects or delegates, so neither did my answer. Looks like you've solved it with UIPageVC, glad to see a happy ending.

Comment: Number 3 mentioned a delegate. Although not as clearly as I had in mind. Either way thanks for the suggestion I am sure it will be of use for other readers.